Nextjs app folder unnecessary function call
I've just switched to the app folder structure. I use mock data and simulate data delay with the -sleep- function. I am fetching the tabs items that creates the tabs and I fetch the related table data separately in their own components and wrapped them with Suspense.
export default async function Home({searchParams,
}: {
  searchParams: { [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined }
}) {
  const location =
    (searchParams.location as string) ??
    'country-1'

  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col  p-24">
      <div className="mb-6">
        <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading locations...</div>}>
          <ShopLocations selectedLocation={location} />
        </Suspense>
      </div>
      <h3 className="text-lg font-semibold text-gray-800 mb-2">
        Operator(s)
      </h3>
      <div className="rounded bg-white max-w-screen-md border">
        <div className="bg-light-5 grid grid-cols-[1fr_100px] gap-x-10 border-b px-2 py-2.5 text-sm font-medium tracking-tight lg:gap-x-24 lg:px-4 ">
          <span>Operator</span>
          <span>In Stock</span>
        </div>
        <Suspense fallback={<div className='p-3'>Loading....</div>} key={location}>
          <ShopItems selectedLocation={location} />
        </Suspense>
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}

Locations component
export default async function ShopLocations({
  selectedLocation,
}: {
  selectedLocation: string
}) {
  const locations = (await getLocations()) as string[]

  return (
    <>
      <h3 className="text-lg font-semibold mb-2">Choose a location</h3>
      <Tabs defaultValue={selectedLocation}>
        <TabsList>
          {locations.map((location: string) => (
            <TabsTrigger
              key={location}
              value={location}
              className="capitalize"
              asChild
            >
              <Link
                href={`?${new URLSearchParams({ location })}`}
                scroll={false}
              >
                {location}
              </Link>
            </TabsTrigger>
          ))}
        </TabsList>
      </Tabs>
    </>
  )
}

Table component
export default async function ShopItems({
  selectedLocation,
}: {
  selectedLocation: string
}) {
  const { items } = (await getItemsByLocation(selectedLocation)) as {
    items: any[]
  }

  return items.map((item: any) => (
    <div className="border-b last:border-b-0" key={item.id}>
      <div
        className='text-dark grid grid-cols-[1fr_100px] items-center gap-x-10 gap-y-10 px-2 py-4 text-sm tracking-tight last:border-b-0 lg:gap-x-24 lg:px-4'
      >
        <div>
        {item.name}
        </div>

        <div>{item.stock}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  ))
}

fetcher functions
export async function getItemsByLocation(location?: any) {
  const url = `${`http://localhost:3000/api/purchase-proxies`}/${location}`
  try {
    const data = await fetch(url)

  await sleep(3000) // Simulate network latency
    return data
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(' ~ error:', error)
    if (error instanceof Error) {
      throw new Error(error.message)
    }
  }
}

export async function getLocations() {
  const url = `${`http://localhost:3000/api/purchase-proxies/locations`}`
  try {
    const data = await fetch(url)
    await sleep(2000) // Simulate network latency
    return data
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(' ~ error:', error)
    if (error instanceof Error) {
      throw new Error(error.message)
    }
  }
}

When I first open or refresh the page, I see the Loading texts for tabs and table as expected, but if I click an item on tabs, I expect query parameter change immediately and Loading text for table shows immediately. but first its calls the function of the locations again (getLocations) which cause 2 second delay before change query params then calling table data function. I wasn't have this problem on pages structure.
see gif example here

when searchParams change the whole page get rerender in server side. but as i see you dont need to fetch locations each time. so move locations component to layout level and it should solve your problem.

but I need location from searchParams in locations component

you have that, when you click on location page url get changed. it doesn't matter where your location component is. and to load locations you no need any param.

in ShopLocations you didnt used selectedLocation so it is unnecessary

I am using it to select default selected value ​​in tabs. <Tabs defaultValue={selectedLocation}>

so i guess you have to use context to tracking selected location and avoid refetching.
